# Blue X using ddms screenshot tool

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, screenshot, ddms

I'm trying to take a screenshot of my device and when I bring up the screenshot tool within ddms I see a large blue X with a white background.  I've tried it with several emulators and screens sizes but I get the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was having is that you need to have a `skin` associated with the emulator. I originally had the `Skin with dynamic hardware controls` option selected which gave me this result.  When I changed the skin to any of the normal skins everything worked fine.